# QGIS error on rasterize vector to raster tool

Tags: qgis

[image]I keep getting this error on QGIS when trying to create a raster layer someone please help me troubleshoot

```
ERROR 1: Wrong value for -ts parameter.
Usage: gdal_rasterize [-b band]* [-i] [-at] 
{[-burn value]* | [-a attribute_name] | [-3d]} [-add] 
[-l layername]* [-where expression] [-sql select_statement] 
[-dialect dialect] [-of format] [-a_srs srs_def] [-to "NAME=VALUE"]* 
[-co "NAME=VALUE"]* [-a_nodata value] [-init value]* 
[-te xmin ymin xmax ymax] [-tr xres yres] [-tap] [-ts width height] 
[-ot {Byte/Int16/UInt16/UInt32/Int32/Float32/Float64/ 
CInt16/CInt32/CFloat32/CFloat64}] [-optim {[AUTO]/VECTOR/RASTER}] [-q] 
<src_datasource> <dst_filename>
Process returned error code 1
```

Comment: ERROR 4: `file:///C:/Users/Shane%20Adair/Downloads/ExcelExport%20(36).csv?type=csv&maxFields=10000&detectTypes=yes&xField=Load%20Longitude&yField=Load%20Latitude&crs=EPSG:4326&spatialIndex=no&subsetIndex=no&watchFile=no' does not exist in the file system, and is not recognized as a supported dataset name.
Process returned error code 1
Execution completed in 0.05 seco

Comment: i already change the vertical resolution and I keep getting these errors

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the tool window with the parameters you have insert.
Some tools require all parameters to be completed.

Comment: how do I add the print screen file to the comment board

Comment: I tried to change the name of the data set and nothing happened

Comment: I did not figure this question out I just figured out how to add the picture

Comment: I think the width and height should be the same number.

Comment: that didnt help